# What is the equivalent of System.currenttimemillis() in Tcl

Tags: java, time, tcl

What is the equivalent of Java's

```
System.currenttimemillis();
```

in Tcl ?

Comment: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/clock.htm Came up as the first item on a google search.

Comment: That came up as number 2 on my search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clock milliseconds` 
There is a reference manual [here](http://tmml.sourceforge.net/doc/tcl/clock.html)